# Using Robocopy for incremental backup to OneDrive connected as network share

Tags: windows-10, network-shares, onedrive, robocopy

I have OneDrive set up as a network share rather than syncing the local OneDrive folder.  I'm trying to use robocopy on Windows 10 in a batch script which will run as a daily scheduled task to "mirror" a set of local folders on the network share.  The command syntax I'm trying to use is this (N: is the drive mapped to OneDrive):

```
robocopy <local folder> N:<remote folder> /MIR /FFT /XO /COPY:DAT /DCOPY:T /R:3 /W:10 /NP /NDL
```

The problem is that the files on the network share all have the timestamp from when they were copied, rather than that of the local copy of the file (which I thought /COPY:DAT would enforce).  The files are all being copied, but the next time I run the script, it looks like every file is copied again even it if hasn't changed, rather than the /XO switch coming into play to only copy new/changed files.

Is it not possible for robocopy to retain the original timestamp when the destination is a network share, or is it a problem that the network share is really OneDrive?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken OneDrive is build on Sharepoint and as far as I can tell you can't tell it to not temper with files. I haven't checked for OneDrive but at least with Sharepoint it might actually modify office documents. You could easily check that by using a comparison tool. From my experience robocopy isn't up to the task in this case. Using `/m` might work as it is a bit that's being set and reset or you might be able to use `/maxage`.

Comment: @Seth You might want to convert your comment to a full answer, because that is exactly the problem with OneDrive. It really is Sharepoint with a webdav share on top and it doesn't adhere to the normal behavior that you would expect from a real file-system.

Comment: The old [SyncToy](https://www.filecroco.com/download-synctoy/download/) was said to write to SharePoint in WebDAV mode and keep timestamps. Although old, it might still work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem in this case might be OneDrive and the technology it's based on. I have tried to do this in the past and wasn't able to get OneDrive (or SharePoint which seems to be the backend) to stop tempering with files. Not only was it modifiying timestamp but also the content of Office documents.

Using robocopy you might be able to employ a different set of parameters to make this work. This will be a bit broader in terms of what it does but it should allow you to copy the files you need.

I haven't tried those myself yet but using the "classic" backup solution of setting and resetting the archive bit using `/m` might work.

> /m    Copies only files for which the Archive attribute is set, and resets the Archive attribute.

Another option might be to use a (mix) of date selections because you probably know when you run that script. This is prone to more errors as there are operations that might not change dates on files.

> /min:  Specifies the minimum file size (to exclude files smaller than n bytes).
>
> /maxage:   Specifies the maximum file age (to exclude files older than n days or date).
>
> /minage:   Specifies the minimum file age (exclude files newer than n days or date).
>
> /maxlad:   Specifies the maximum last access date (excludes files unused since n).
>
> /minlad:   Specifies the minimum last access date (excludes files used since n) If n is less than 1900, n specifies the number of days. Otherwise, n specifies a date in the format YYYYMMDD.

Essentially you'd have to rely on using some selection that's based solely on your local files. To delete files on the remote site you'd still be able ot use `/purge`.